# the adjoint operator of the inner product of integral

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Given $f$ and $g$ polynomial functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the height degree $1$, 
and $T(bx+a)=ax+b$
and the inner product integral$\int_0^1fg\enspace dx$.

find $T^*$.

I thought that I should just take the transpose matrix of $T$ but it seems an incorrect answer. Why? I thought that on $\mathbb{R}$, $T^*$ must be the transpose

Comment: What do you mean by "the transpose matrix of $T$"?  $T$ is not a matrix, so how would we take its transpose?

Comment: We can write it as a matrix, as it is a linear finite operator.

Comment: With respect to which basis? If you look at the matrix of $T$ relative to an orthonormal basis, then the conjugate-transpose trick works.  In general, however, it will not.  So if you look at $T$ relative to the "standard basis" $\{1,x\}$, taking the conjugate transpose won't work.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by integral f,g?  Over what interval are we taking that integral?

Comment: great point! thanks! can you solve it then? the integral is over a common variable. let say x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how we would solve the problem using the definition.  For a linear map $T$ on the inner product space $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, $T^*$ is defined so that for all $f,g \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ we have
$$
\langle Tf,g\rangle = \langle f, T^*g \rangle.
$$
Now, suppose $f(x) = a_1 x + b_1$ and $g(x) = a_2 x + b_2$.  We then have
$$
\langle Tf, g \rangle = \int_0^1 (b_1 x + a_1)(a_2 x + b_2) = 
\int_0^1 [a_2 b_1 x^2 + (a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2)x + a_1 b_2]\,dx \\
= \frac 13 a_{2}b_1 + \frac 12(a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2) + a_1 b_2.
$$
Now, in terms of $a_2$ and $b_2$, we want to find $\alpha,\beta$ such that we'll have $T^*g = \alpha x + \beta$, which is to say that for all pairs $a_1,b_1$ we have
$$
\langle f, T^*g \rangle = \frac 13 a_{2}b_1 + \frac 12(a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2) + a_1 b_2  \\
= \left(\frac 12 a_2 + b_2 \right)a_1 + \left(\frac 13 a_2 + \frac 12 b_2\right)b_1
 \\
= \int_{0}^1 (a_1x + b_1)(\alpha x + \beta)\,dx\\
= \int_0^1 [\alpha a_1 x^2 + (b_1 \alpha + a_1 \beta)x + b_1 \beta]dx\\
= \frac 13 \alpha a_1 + \frac 12 (b_1 \alpha + a_1 \beta)+ b_1 \beta  \\
= \left(\frac 13 \alpha + \frac 12 \beta \right)a_1 + \left(\frac 12 \alpha + \beta\right) b_1
$$
In other words, we are solving system of equations:
$$
\frac 13 \alpha + \frac 12 \beta = \frac 12 a_2 + b_2, \quad  
\frac 12 \alpha + \beta = \frac 13 a_2 + \frac 12 b_2.
$$
**Note:** We can get the above equations in a neater way if we separately note that $\langle Tf,g\rangle = \langle f, T^*g \rangle$ for $f(x) = 1$ and $f(x) = x$.

Assuming my calculations are correct, this yields
$$
\alpha = 4a_2 + 9b_2, \quad \beta = - \frac 53 a_2 - 4 b_2.
$$
Correspondingly, the adjoint to $T$ is given by
$$
T^*(ax + b) = (4a + 9b)x - 5a/3 - 4b.
$$

---

Another approach, using Gram Schmidt.  We build an orthonormal basis from $\{1,x\}$.  Since $1$ already has norm 1, we compute
$$
\langle 1,x \rangle = \int_0^1 x\,dx = \frac 12
$$
which means that
$$
x^{\perp} = x - \langle 1,x \rangle \cdot 1 = x - \frac 12.
$$
To normalize this vector, we compute
$$
\langle x^\perp,x^{\perp} \rangle = 
\int_0^1 (x - \frac 12)^2\,dx = \frac 1{12}
$$
which means that our orthonormal basis is
$$
\{f_1,f_2\} = \{1, \frac{x^\perp}{\|x^\perp\|}\} = \{1, \frac 1{\sqrt{12}} (x - \frac 12)\}.
$$
We find that
$$
T(f_1) = x = \frac 12 f_1 + \sqrt{12} f_2 \\
T(f_2) = \frac 1{\sqrt{12}} (1 - \frac 12 x)
= \frac 1{\sqrt{12}} - \frac 12 f_2 - \frac{1}{4\sqrt{12}}
= \frac{3}{4\sqrt{12}} f_1 - \frac 12 f_2.
$$
So, the matrix of $T$ relative to this orthonormal basis is
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{1/2 & \frac{3}{4\sqrt{12}} \\ \sqrt{12} & - \frac 12}.
$$
The matrix of the adjoint is simply the transpose of the above.

---

A more elegant approach, using a judicious choice of orthonormal basis.  We know that $x + 1$ is an eigenvector of $T$.  Apply the Gram Schmidt process to the basis $\{v_1,v_2\} = \{x+1,1\}$.  First, normalizing $x + 1$ yields
$$
\langle v_1,v_1 \rangle = \int_0^1 (x+1)^2\,dx = \frac 73
$$
so our first vector is $u_1 = \sqrt{\frac 37} (x+1)$. We compute
$$
v_2^\perp = v_2 - \langle v_2,u_1 \rangle u_1 = v_2 - \frac 37 \left(\int_0^1 x(x+1)\,dx\right) (x+1)\\
= x - \frac 37 \cdot \frac 56 (x+1) 
= x - \frac 5{14} (x+1) = \frac{1}{14}(9x - 5)
$$
Normalizing this yields $u_2 = \frac{9x - 5}{\sqrt{7}}$.  We then compute
$$
T(u_1) = 1 \cdot u_1 + 0 \cdot u_2\\
T(u_2) = \frac{-5x + 9}{\sqrt7} = \cdots = \alpha u_1 + \beta u_2
$$
From there, we know that the matrix of $T$ relative to this basis is
$$
\pmatrix{1&\alpha\\0 & \beta}
$$
and that the matrix of its adjoint is the (conjugate) transpose,
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\\alpha & \beta}.
$$

Comment: wow, amazing! thank you so much!

Comment: @MrP I was hoping that we could find a nice matrix approach, but it looks like going by definition really is the way to go here.  And you're welcome.

Comment: Hi Ben, I got a similar question except that T(f) is now f' + 3f and the integral is from -1 to 1 instead. I tried to use the orthonormal basis method and get the matrix representation of T as (3 1 0 3) (which is the same as when I use the standard basis interestingly) and thus T* as (3 0 1 3). Do you think this is correct? I checked my answer again the textbook's answer and it's not.