# Finding adjoint over an inner product with integral

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $f$ and $g$ polynomial functions $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with the height degree $1$, and $(f)= f' + 3f$ and the inner product $\int_{-1}^1 fg \,dx$.

Find $^*$.

I tried to express $T$ in terms of its orthonormal basis and got $
\left(\begin{matrix}
3 & \sqrt{3} \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
$
so $T^* =
\left(\begin{matrix}
3 & 0 \\
\sqrt{3} & 3 \\
\end{matrix}\right)?
$

Comment: Which orthonormal basis?

Comment: Note that $T=D+3I$ where $I$ (the identity map) is self-adjoint. So, you only need to find $D^*.$

Comment: Hint: let $D^*(cx+d)=ex+f$ where $e,f$ depend on $c,d.$ By definition of the adjoint,
$$\forall a,b\in\Bbb R\quad\int_{-1}^1(ax+b)(ex+f)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^1a(cx+d)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Calculate and identify: $(e,f)=?$

Comment: I orthonormalised the standard basis to get the orthonormal basis. So you mean my T* is incorrect? We can't just transpose T to get T*?

Comment: I only mean we want to see the basis explicitely. Otherwise we cannot tell you whether your $T$ is correct (if it is, then $T^*$ will also be, yes). And I indicated a direct method, without basis.

Comment: My basis is {1/sqrt(2), x/sqrt(2/3)}.

Comment: Why is there the need to orthonormalize it?

Comment: I agree with your basis. Not with the $1$ in your matrix.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know why but in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437232/the-adjoint-operator-of-the-inner-product-of-integral/3437281#3437281 it says we need an orthonormal basis for the transpose trick to work. In my curriculum, the transpose trick only works in the standard inner product over C so I think the trick won't work with an integral inner product.

Comment: [The "transpose trick" in euclidean spaces (or "adjoint trick" in hermitian spaces)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758120/how-do-i-prove-the-adjoint-matrix-is-the-adjoint-of-the-operator) works only in an orthonormal basis (or product thereof by a constant) because it is only in an orthonormal basis that $\langle u,v\rangle=\sum u_kv_k.$

Comment: @AnneBauval my bad. I fixed my matrix. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes it is. Did you try my method? I find it simpler.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. It's midnight here. I think these comments should be moved to chat which I'm not sure how to get there. If not, a moderator will get in soon haha. Also, what are uk vk in your formula? The elements in u and v?

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you @AnneBauval and Khanh. I should try to prove this stuff again, it's been a long time

Comment: $u_k,v_k$ are the coordinates of $u,v$ in the (orthonormal) basis.